# Throw error whenever attempting to use geoproject command in terminal

Tags: node.js, d3.js, data-visualization

I keep getting the same error anytime I try to use the geoproject command.

I have the latest version of node and D3 downloaded.

error message:

```
Parkers-MacBook-Pro-2:proj parkerbarton$ geoproject
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'resolve'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/d3-geo-projection/bin/resolve.js:2:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
```

Answer (score 0):

tldr; Just re-install to get the new version of d3-geo-projection.

```
npm install -g d3-geo-projection
```

There's an issue for this here: https://github.com/d3/d3-geo-projection/issues/161

And there's a fix for this up on a pull request, but it hasn't gotten pulled in yet.  You could wait for the fix or in the meantime you can probably just add 'require' into the same place in {global-install-location}/node_modules/d3-geo-projection/package.json

https://github.com/d3/d3-geo-projection/pull/162/commits/43105df62b784f0645cb3d4cb0b0fa98c8924c87

UPDATE: It's up on 2.6, just re-install d3-geo-projection.